# What is the difference between tableViewCell and xib/nib in swift ? And when to use what?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, xib, nib

I am so confused that whatever we can do through .xib/nib same thing can be done through normal tableViewCell. So whats the difference between them and when to use what?

Comment: I would just create everything programatically

Comment: Before the ability to design multiple cells directly in the table view in IB you had to use .xib (back then .nib). For many folks it's just still a common practice. But nowadays actually xibs are only useful if the cell is supposed to appear in multiple different locations or if Interface Builder is not being used at all.

Comment: Could you define "normal tableViewCell"?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a TableViewCell using xib to design your custom cell and you can connect xib (design) with swift file of cell.

> *CustomButtonTableViewCell.swift*

> *CustomButtonTableViewCell.xib*

Using xib to create TableView Cells is the better way if your TableView has multiple custom cells.

---

You can create extension for TableView to register cells.

```
extension UITableView {

func registerCell(identifier:String) {
    self.register(UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    self.tableFooterView = UIView()
    self.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    self.separatorStyle = .none
} }
```

then you can register all custom cells to TableView and use it in UIViewController class.

```
tableView.registerCell(identifier: identifierButton)
tableView.registerCell(identifier: identifierTF)
tableView.registerCell(identifier: identifierAttText)
tableView.registerCell(identifier: identifierImage)
```